# Help with mobile page, fixed div at top and iframe below

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Hi I'm looking help with a mobile site I'm developing.  I'm trying to get a page with a toolbar at the top of the screen that has previous and next buttons, with most of the viewport displaying an iframe containing 3rd party websites.

I have a few issues getting this working.  The first is to have the toolbar fixed at the top.  Mobile browsers don't natively support fixed positioning so I've achieved a workable solution where I move the toolbar back to the top of the screen with the window.onresize event.  I can't move the div while scrolling as mobile browsers disable DOM rendering between the touchstart and touchend events.

The main issue I am now having is that the div toolbar displays correctly at the top however the iframe is zoomed to the top left corner of the site it has loaded.  You cannot zoom out at all.  You can only zoom in further and pan the site.  You can only really view the iframe site in 100% of the viewport when it's loaded by itself.

Here's a wireframe of what I want to achieve..

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's an idea of the code I'm using to achieve this..

There's also javascript that modifies the top and left css values of #wrapper when you scroll the screen using the window.onresize event.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta
     name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width; 
             initial-scale=1;
             maximum-scale=1;
             minimum-scale=1; 
             user-scalable=yes;"
    />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="width:320px;top:0;height:86px; position:absolute; z-index:1000; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:5px solid #4B90B7;">
<!-- Header markup -->
</div>
<div id="iframe" style="height: 750px;position:absolute; top:100px; width:100%" >

<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%">
<!-- iframe -->
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure mobile browsers don't support fixed positioning? It'd be nice to know which browsers are you testing and what code you've got at this moment, so that we can better grasp and answer your question.

Comment: Read point 4 at the below..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009577-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5

CSS fixed positioning works in Safari on iPhone and iPad, but not as you might expect. While elements that use fixed positioning in Safari on Mac OS X and Windows always stay on screen, elements that use fixed positioning in Safari on iPhone and iPad can end up offscreen as users zoom and pan the webpage.

Comment: I'm testing on android and safari mobile

Comment: Have edited the question with parts of my markup

Comment: I see.  So the question is getting it stay on screen even with zooming and without affecting the zooming and panning of iframe?  Now that's a problem.  Good question.  You only need to test on stock browsers?

Comment: Yeh sorry it's a bit of a complicated one to explain, I'm quite new to developing for mobile devices as I'm sure a lot of people are at present.

Comment: I only need to test on iPhone and Android browsers, have an HTC Desire and iPhone 4 for testing.

Comment: have you thought about using a framework, like jQuery Mobile or Sencha Touch? They are well designed for both iOS and Android browsers.

Comment: I'm using the mobile boilerplate developed by the same guys who did the HTML5 boilerplate.  Have had a look at jquery mobile but that doesn't have what I'm looking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've moved on by now, but for anyone Googling, I ended up dealing with a similar situation by applying CSS Scale.  Re-positioning was a total nightmare, but you can get it to work.  This works on an inline scrollview, and I assume it would work on an iframe:

Question/answer here:  [Scale HTML content using JQuery Mobile & Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403093/scale-html-content-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap)

Additionally, it may be worth looking into ChildBrowser vs. iframe.  I'm experimenting with it now, but so far it looks useful:

https://github.com/alunny/ChildBrowser

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd chip in another way to do a "fixed" position element in mobile browsers. You can simply give the content element a height and `overflow: auto`. Make sure the sum of the heights of the fixed header and the content element equals the page height.

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">fixed header</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
</div>
```

---

```
#page {
    position:relative;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1.5em;
}

#content {
    top: 1.5em;
    position:relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/BWA7j/

Comment: tried that and it doesn't do what I need.  The iframe site still displays zoomed in.