# Scale HTML content using JQuery Mobile & Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, resize, viewport

I need to dynamically load content from HTML emails into some type of content area within my HTML so that it is scaled to fit, exactly the way the native mail apps do for iPhone/Android.  I have spent two days Googling and testing to no avail.  I'm loading the HTML content (which is often set to width=600 or something nice), but rather than scaling, it is appearing as follows:

[iPhone Simulator Example](http://strandstudios.com/img/iphonesim.png)

The HTML is very simple:

```
<div data-role="page" id="messagedetailpage" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content" id="messagedetailcontainer"></div>
</div>
```

The sanitized email HTML is loaded into a div (messagedetailcontainer), at which point I've tried the following things:

1. Resize the viewport with: $.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0,5";
2. Call several triggers on the div such as: $("#messagedetailcontainer").append(data.msg_body).trigger('updatelayout');
3. Same as #2, but with 'create', 'resize', 'load', and 'change'.
4. $(window).resize();
5. Scrapping the div and putting it in an iFrame (no luck at all)
6. I've research iScroll, ScrollView, various autoscale.js examples, but nothing seems to fit my need.

I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible.  If anyone can help me I will be eternally grateful.  I don't mind being stuck for hours, but once it turns to days it starts to become maddening.  And sadly this is a show-stopper for me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the width of the view-port and the width of the content, then scale the content down based on a ratio of the two:

```
var venderPrefix = ($.browser.webkit)  ? 'Webkit' : 
                   ($.browser.mozilla) ? 'Moz' :
                   ($.browser.ms)      ? 'Ms' :
                   ($.browser.opera)   ? 'O' : '';
var ratio = $(window).width() / $('#newContent').width();
$('#newContent').css(venderPrefix + 'Transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')');
```

Comment: Thanks, Jasper! It's changing the size of the content, but:  1) The container is not adapting to the size of the content, and since the content could arrive in any HTML structure, it's impossible to figure out the widest element.  I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the parent to adapt to the content width so I can get a correct ratio.  2) If I force the ratio to be correct, the element gets positioned very far down the page, and looks like it is cropped in half, like this:  [Updated Example](http://strandstudios.com/img/iphonesim2.png)  I'll keep playing with it and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Try as I might, I can't get this to work.  I can get the width of the container after loading the HTML, but once I scale it, all sorts of erratic behavior starts - namely that it positions the scaled element toward the right-middle part of the page, yet the page remains expanded to the size it would have been if the content had been there.  I'm unable to reposition it with CSS.  It's not pretty.  I even tried applying the content to an invisible element, appending it, scaling it, then making it visible, but the result is always the same. 4 hours of banging my head - any thoughts are welcome...

Comment: Getting closer by using this, but still needs work:  `code`var adjustHeight = (((containerHeight - (containerHeight * ratio)) / 2) + 10) * -1;
      var adjustWidth = ((containerWidth * ratio) - (windowWidth / 2) + 20) * -1; $("#messagedetailcontainer").css(venderPrefix + 'Transform', 'scale(' + ratio + ')')
      $("#messagedetailcontainer").css({position:'relative', top: adjustHeight + 'px', left: adjustWidth + 'px'});`code`

Comment: I was hoping to stumble across some built-in, elegant way to do this, but it appears brute force is the only solution.  Jasper, for pointing me in the right direction on this solution, I'll mark this the answer.  Thanks!